# Semmless password reset management for web services

Tags: authentication, restful-authentication, webservice-client, change-password

We have Integration between applications where authentication is controlled by the applicaiton which is providing the service.

The provider service would want to change the password at a predefined frequency for security purposes.

Consuming applicaitons have to change the password at the same time when provider service resets the password. This is not automatic and might involve downtime at the consuming application.

We are planning to automate this by ensuring consuming applicaiton switches to new password if there is credential error recieved from provider service ( basically retry using new password ).
By doing this consumer applicaiton need not go though an outage when the password reset happens. (There will be a configuration change needed in the consumer applicaiton to set the new password, which will be done days before the actual password change )

Is there any better way of achieving this ? Since this might be a common problem - is there any pattern or utility to handle password rotation seamlessly.?

We already have a solution for retry - but wanted to know if there is better solution